# a "consistent" problem in Rudin Riesz Rep.Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

In Rudin's proof,when construct $\mu$ and $\sigma-algebra$,he said:

For every open set $V$ in $X$, define $\mu(V)=\sup\{\Lambda f : f\prec V\}$.Then define $\mu(E)=\inf\{\mu(V):E\subset V, V \text{ open}\}$ for every subset $E$ of $X$. (It is consistent with the above definition.

Why are they consistent?Just take $V$ as $E$.Here $V$ is open in $X$ while $E$ is arbitray.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see the problem with the definition. By consistent he means that if $V$ is open then both definitions of $\mu(V)$ give the same result. And they do. In the second definition we have
$$\mu(V) = \inf \{\mu(U): V \subset U, U \mbox{ open } \}$$
and this infimum is attained when $U = V$ since the special definition of $\mu$ for open sets has an obvious monotonicity property.

Comment: You want to say that if we consider open set $V$ in $X$,then the two definitions are consistent,is it right?If consider general set,then we should use the second defintion.Can I mean this?

Comment: @mathon Precisely.